# inline assembly in visual studio 2005 (32bit)?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

Can I do inline assembly in visual studio 2005 (32 bit) ?

(I am pretty sure the (64 bit) version no longer allows inline assembly or "__asm".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, using `__asm`.  See the [Inline Assembler documentation for VS 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).